# In illustrator how do you overlay an image to give it the same background texture and then darker those spots?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a textured background and then on the individual texts I hit the overlay option. I like this texture but now the text is too light. I would like to have the text as a darker shade now but retain the texture. Is this possible?

here is the image thus far:
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

See the cartoon:

[image]

1. Have 2 copies of your text - one quite dark grey and one of the wanted color. Here the dark grey has R=G=B=51.
2. Place the dark one with blending mode = Color Burn
3. Place the other copy on the top with blending mode = Color

Step 2 can be enough, if the resulted color happens to be good for the purpose, but this way you get more flexibility.

You can reduce the effect by reducing the opacities.

Answer (score 1):

Select the text or image or whatever and change it's **Blending Mode** on the **Transparency Panel**. Different blending modes will result in different appearances.

For objects such as text, you can also alter the fill color and it will cause blending modes to interact differently.